# jquery: target nth instance of class when it isn't the only class of div

Tags: jquery, class, target

I have a list of similar div's which all have class `a` assigned to them and some have `a` AND `b` classes.

I want to find out the `b` index of the currently selected div.

If both classes exist, the index returned is of the "like" class `a` and not of the class I'm looking for `b`.

The div's look like this

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="clicker">1st</div>
</div>
<div class="a b">
    <div class="clicker">2nd (1st instance of class b - index 0)</div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="clicker">3rd</div> 
</div>
<div class="a b">
    <div class="clicker">4th (2nd instance of class b - index 1)</div>
</div>
```

and I'm targeting them like this

```
$(".clicker").click(function(){
    var yi = $(this).closest(".b").index();
    // yi should have the index of .b
});
```

How can find the index of just `b`?

http://jsfiddle.net/zgn1fv47/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the selection of the index so that it only matches the `a` and `b` classes;

```
var yi= $(this).closest(".b").index(".a.b");
```